# Latex: проблемы с компиляцией tikzpicture

Tags: latex

Знаю, что код рабочий, но на моем ноуте не работает. Подскажите, пжл, в чем может быть ошибка.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
% alpha = (0.924,22.5), beta = (0.383,-22.5)

% alpha and beta complex items values

\def\arho{0.924}
\def\aphi{22.5}
\def\brho{0.383}
\def\bphi{-22.5}

% draw axes
\draw [-latex] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
% draw unit circle
\draw (0,0) circ

le (1cm);
% drav axes descriptions
\draw (-1.0,   0) node[anchor=south east] {$-1$};
\draw ( 1.0,   0) node[anchor=south west] {$1$};
\draw (   0,-1.0) node[anchor=north west] {$-i$};
\draw (   0, 1.0) node[anchor=south west] {$i$};

%% DRAWING alpha an beta
% angles
\filldraw[gray,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (\arho,0) arc (0:\aphi:\arho cm);
\filldraw[gray,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (\brho,0) arc (0:\bphi:\brho cm);
\draw (\arho,0) arc (0:\aphi:\arho cm);
\draw (\brho,0) arc (0:\bphi:\brho cm);
% radial circles
\draw [dotted] (0,0) circle (\arho cm);
\draw [dotted] (0,0) circle (\brho cm);
% vectors
\draw [thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (xyz polar cs:angle=\aphi,radius=\arho);
\draw (xyz polar cs:angle=\aphi,radius={\arho +0.1}) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (xyz polar cs:angle=\bphi,radius=\brho);
\draw (xyz polar cs:angle=\bphi,radius={\brho +0.1}) node {$\beta$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Выдает такие ошибки:
[image: Выдает такие ошибки]

Comment: Так коды ТеХ не выкладывают. Целиком нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ, большей частью, содержится в сообщении об ошибках.

1. Вы ведь пытались компилировать latex-ом прямо приведенный кусок? Без полагающейся преамбулы и даже без `\documentclass`, `\begin{document} .. \end{document}`.
   И естественно, latex ни за что не признает этот набор команд без нормально оформленного документа.
2. В приведенном коде у Вас на одной строке стоит `\draw (0,0) circ`, а через пустую строку еще от этой же команды остаток: `le (1cm);`. На это тоже компилятор вполне обоснованно ругается.

Итого, исправляем указанные ошибки и собираем, например, командой `pdflatex thisfile.tex` (вместо `thisfile.tex` название своего файла подставите).

Подозреваю, что Вы не знакомы с latex, поэтому еще добавлю пару слов про добавленный код: класс документа `standalone` означает, что на выходе Вы хотите получить просто рисунок, а не документ, скажем, размера A4 (или любого другого, какой заказываете); 
вторая строка - это включение пакета с определениями команд `tikz`, без которого тоже будут ошибки; ну и `\begin{document}` и  `\end{document}` - определяют тело самого документа.

Естественно, если Вам нужно вставить такой рисунок прямо в уже существующий latex-документ, то Вам нужно только в преамбулу добавить пакет (`\usepackage{tikz}`) и вставить окружение `tikzpicture` с его содержимым.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
% alpha = (0.924,22.5), beta = (0.383,-22.5)
% alpha and beta complex items values

\def\arho{0.924}
\def\aphi{22.5}
\def\brho{0.383}
\def\bphi{-22.5}

% draw axes
\draw [-latex] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);
\draw [-latex] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
% draw unit circle
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);

% drav axes descriptions
\draw (-1.0,   0) node[anchor=south east] {$-1$};
\draw ( 1.0,   0) node[anchor=south west] {$1$};
\draw (   0,-1.0) node[anchor=north west] {$-i$};
\draw (   0, 1.0) node[anchor=south west] {$i$};

%% DRAWING alpha an beta
% angles
\filldraw[gray,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (\arho,0) arc (0:\aphi:\arho cm);
\filldraw[gray,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (\brho,0) arc (0:\bphi:\brho cm);
\draw (\arho,0) arc (0:\aphi:\arho cm);
\draw (\brho,0) arc (0:\bphi:\brho cm);
% radial circles
\draw [dotted] (0,0) circle (\arho cm);
\draw [dotted] (0,0) circle (\brho cm);
% vectors
\draw [thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (xyz polar cs:angle=\aphi,radius=\arho);
\draw (xyz polar cs:angle=\aphi,radius={\arho +0.1}) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (xyz polar cs:angle=\bphi,radius=\brho);
\draw (xyz polar cs:angle=\bphi,radius={\brho +0.1}) node {$\beta$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

В результате получится что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]